# VBA Copy Paste is Removing Borders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm copying and pasting values from one workbook to another using VBA code.  However, when I paste, the borders in the destination worksheet are being deleted.  How can I maintain the borders when pasting?

Below is my code:

```
With wsSource
    .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy wsDestination.Range("A3")
End With
```

I have read that the `PasteSpecial` method could be of use, but I don't know how to implement it in the above code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
With wsSource
    .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy

    wsDestination.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

Whenever in doubt, record a macro ;)